# Minimisation problem in Sobolev space

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I am given a minimisation problem of finding $p \in \mathbb{P}^2$:

$\vert\vert e^x - p\vert\vert_{H^1(\Omega)}^2=\inf_{q \in \mathbb{P^2}}\vert\vert e^x -q\vert\vert_{H^1(\Omega)}$.

The norm $H^1$ is defined as a standard $W^{1,2}$ norm.

I could solve the problem using the standard procedure of minismising a functional, but the condition $p \in \mathbb{P}^2$ really confuses me: I assume $\mathbb{P}$ is a space of all polynomials, but then using  $\mathbb{P}^2$ doesn't make much sense for me here. Is something wrong with my understanding of the problem? How should I proceed with solving it?

Comment: What is $\mathbf{P}^2$? I would guess that these are polynomials up to degree $2$?

Comment: I thought like that, but for example [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-it-be-proved-that-the-space-mathbb-P-of-all-polynomials-is-an-infinite-dimensional-space) $\mathbb{P}$ is used a space of all polynomials. 
Anyway, do you have any hints if $\mathbb{P}^2$ are polynomials up to degree 2?